# How to display text in an MVC view with htmlattrbutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", 
"Manage", "Account", 
routeValues: null, 
htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

I just want to display the text (with the correct htmlattribute) (i.e. **no link**)

Could you help me with the correct syntax please?

Comment: no link means it should look like normal text??

Comment: Sorry, I meant rendered with the correct htmlattribute, just the text rendered correctly, no link

Comment: i have given an answer, also check how you are giving html attributes,  try my answer's code

Comment: What I want is the text "Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!" rendered without a link using the htmlattributes in the code.

Comment: john why don't use @Html.Label

Comment: What does **no link** mean?  Is it visual, or you don't want an html anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly,you want to show the text inside your link without an achor tag, but with your html attributes (`title` attributes)

Try this

```
<span title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.GetUserName() !</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use **Url.Action** method.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName")">
  <span>"Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!"</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't want a link, I just want to render the text.

Comment: Thanks - this sent me on the right route, I'm using a boostrap theme and needed to use class="navbar-text" so that it would display !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text with no link i.e. no anchor element, then just use plain HTML

```
<span title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.GetUserName()!</span>
```

Or if you don't want to enclose it within a `<span>`

```
<text>Hello @User.Identity.GetUserName()!</text>
```

But with this you won't get the `title` attribute since the text is not enclosed within an html tag with which to apply it to.

If you actually want an anchor then you could also use `@Url.Action()` in conjunction with plain HTML

```
<a title="Manage" href="@Url.Action("Manage", "Account")">
    Hello @User.Identity.GetUserName()!
</a>
```